# Choices of tools for graphical performance indications?

Tags: 12.04, performance, monitor

On Windows I had some choices for tools that could display how hard my CPU or disk was working, in a graphical form so I could get a quick view of what's going on.  Is there some analogous set of tools for Ubuntu 12.04?  I've done some simple-minded searches, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has a System Monitor that does this.

- Press the Dash Home button (purple and white at the top left).
- Type System Monitor
- Click on the System Monitor Icon that appears.

There are various tabs for different kinds of statistics.